# Entitymodifiers not working (AndEngine / Android)

Tags: android, andengine

I'm playing around with AndEngine. No docs available for reading, so I'm just shooting in the dark here.

Finally got a splash screen showing. Now I'm trying to add some transitions to it, but no luck here. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
  mHandler.postDelayed(fadeAway, 2500);
}

protected Runnable fadeAway = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // The only child of the scene is our splash sprite
    scene.getLastChild().registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(
        new ScaleModifier(2500, 100.0f, 200.0f),
        new RotationModifier(2500, 0.0f, 78.0f),
        new AlphaModifier(2500, 1.0f, 0.0f)
    ));
  }
};
```

What happens is that the `postDelayed()` runs fine (waiting for 2.5 secs), but then everything goes black immediately. What I was expecting was that the splash screen should zoom in to 200%, then rotate 78 degrees, then fade out, but since everything goes black it feels that the duration of the modifiers is not working.

Is there an apparent error here?

**EDIT**: Alright, found the errors: 1) Apparently the pDuration (first argument) is supposed to be in seconds, not milliseconds as everywhere else  2) In ScaleModifier(), 1.0f equals the original size, so that argument is not in percent as expected.

(No flame, but I'm truly amazed how people managed to learn how to use this library without any documentation. There's not a single comment or note in the whole source code. Did people trial-and-error-reverse-engineered everything to find out how it's supposed to work? Can't believe the author put this vast amount of work for this library and never supplied any docs.)

Comment: Yes, the lacking documentation makes it really hard to use. The examples and the forum posts are vital here.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors is listed below:

- All durations in AndEngine are in seconds.
- Normal scale is `1.0f` not `100.0f`.
- There is no need for Android Handler. You should delay your works in `onUpdate` methods of the engine or other AndEngine stuff.
- You should apply animations only in update thread not anywhere else. `mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(...)`